# Java regular expression cache

Tags: java, regex, caching, replace

I need to replace a print template with placeholders replacing placeholders with real values.
I would like to know if I need to run the regex for each print job or I can use something like a cache of this layout for a faster replacement (the layout is static).

Thanks.

Comment: what do u want to replace? Replacing the code or some data?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).
It's a template library with some extra features. It will replace "Placeholders" in generic files and you can write "code" like "for-loops" into the template file.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can not change the layout-syntax... I must work only in the template parsing.

Comment: You can also write a class for your template, which reads the template file into a list, whereas you save the positions and names of your placeholders, so that you can serialize the class and don't have to reload it everytime you want to replace your placeholders.

Comment: You mean I should store all char-start, char-end position and then use it instead of running another regex?

Comment: A list of tokens (ListA) and another list for keys and placeholdernames (ListB) in which you can identify a Entry in ListA by the placeholdername. Simply look for a placeholder in ListB and change the value in ListA. Finally you iterate over list and rebuild your file together.